# Getting a contradictory error when trying to create an App Client with the AWS Cognito SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

I have had success creating App Clients for a specific Cognito User Pool, but I am having trouble including the final configuration details, which are:

```
AllowedOAuthFlows: ["code"],
AllowedAuthScopes: ["phone", "email", "openid", "profile"],
AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true,
```

If I leave out `AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient`, I am able to run the command but the Allowed Auth Scopes aren't set successfully, and if I INCLUDE the `AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient` like I think I should, then I get this error:

`InvalidParameterException: AllowedOAuthFlows and AllowedOAuthScopes are required if user pool client is allowed to use OAuth flows.`

Which doesn't make sense, as the AllowedOAuthFlows and AllowedOAuthScopes are clearly included in my request object.

I am expecting the AppClient to be created with the following configuration: [desired configuration taken from a hand-configured App Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x6SG.png) rather than get an error.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo - I misspelled the parameter `AllowedOAuthScopes` as `AllowedAuthScopes`. Changing this error allowed the `CognitoIdentityProviderClient` command to work as expected.